# Token error: EOF in multi-line statement

Tags: python, tkinter, eof, easygui

**The following code gives me this error "Token Error: EOF in multi-line statement". What is this error? How can I fix it?**

```
import easygui
import time
namegui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter your name:', title='Name query', default='Gian')
situationgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter your situation:', title='Thought Log(Situation)')
thoughtsgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter your thoughts:', title='Thought Log(Thoughts')
emotionsgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter your emotions: \n Sad, Mad, Hurt, Depressed, Anxious, Tense, etc.', title='Thought Log(Emotions')
behaviorgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter your behavior:', title='Thought Log(Behavior')


thinking_trapsgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please identify your thinking traps: \n \n'
    'FORTUNE-TELLING: This occurs when we predict that things will turn out badly. However, we cannot predict the future because we do not have a magic ball! \n \n'
    'MIND-READING: This happens when we believe that we know what others are thinking and we assume that they are thinking the worst of us. However, we cannot mind-read so we do not know what others are thinking! \n \n'
    'LABELING: Sometimes we talk to ourselves in a mean way and we use a single negative word to describe ourselves. However, this kind of thinking is unfair and we are too complex to be summed up in a single word! \n \n'
    'FILTERING: This happens when we take note of all the bad things that happen, but ignore any good things. \n \n'
    'OVERESTIMATING: This happens when we believe that something that is unlikely to occur is actually about to happen. \n \n'
    'CATASTROPHIZING: This is when we imagine the worst possible thing is about to happen and we will be unable to cope with it. \n \n'
    'OVERGENERALIZING: This is when we use words like always or never to describe situations or events. This is a problematic way of thinking because it does not take all situation or events into account \n \n',
    title='Thought Log(Identify Your Thinking Traps)')

BAI_var = easygui.choicebox(
    msg='Please identify your thinking traps: \n \n',
    title='Thought Log(Identify Your Thinking Traps)',
    choices=('FORTUNE-TELLING: This occurs when we predict that things will turn out badly. However, we cannot predict the future because we do not have a magic ball! \n \n
             'MIND-READING: This happens when we believe that we know what others are thinking and we assume that they are thinking the worst of us. However, we cannot mind-read so we do not know what others are thinking! \n \n'
             'LABELING: Sometimes we talk to ourselves in a mean way and we use a single negative word to describe ourselves. However, this kind of thinking is unfair and we are too complex to be summed up in a single word! \n \n'
             'FILTERING: This happens when we take note of all the bad things that happen, but ignore any good things. \n \n'
             'OVERESTIMATING: This happens when we believe that something that is unlikely to occur is actually about to happen. \n \n'
             'CATASTROPHIZING: This is when we imagine the worst possible thing is about to happen and we will be unable to cope with it. \n \n'
             'OVERGENERALIZING: This is when we use words like always or never to describe situations or events. This is a problematic way of thinking because it does not take all situation or events into account \n \n')


alt_behaviorgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter alternative behavior:', title='Thought Log(Alt Behavior)')
alt_thoughtsgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter alternative thoughts:', title='Thought Log(Alt Thoughts)')
yeargui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current year:', title='Current Year', default='2011')
monthgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current month:', title='Current Month')
daygui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current day:', title='Current Day')
time_hourgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current hour:', title='Current Hour')
time_minutegui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter current minutes:', title='Current Minute')
am_pmgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter either am or pm:', title='AM OR PM')
file = open('Thought Record 1.0.txt', 'a')
file.write(namegui + '\n')
file.write(daygui)
file.write('/')
file.write(monthgui)
file.write('/')
file.write(yeargui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your situation:')
file.write(situationgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your thoughts:')
file.write(thoughtsgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your emotions:')
file.write(emotionsgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your behavior:')
file.write(behaviorgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Thinking traps:')
file.write(thinking_trapsgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Alternative bahvior:')
file.write(alt_behaviorgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Alternative thoughts:')
file.write(alt_thoughtsgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('\n')
file.close()
```

**This error only showed up after I added the following lines of code.**

```
BAI_var = easygui.choicebox(
    msg='Please identify your thinking traps: \n \n',
    title='Thought Log(Identify Your Thinking Traps)',
    choices=('FORTUNE-TELLING: This occurs when we predict that things will turn out badly. However, we cannot predict the future because we do not have a magic ball! \n \n
             'MIND-READING: This happens when we believe that we know what others are thinking and we assume that they are thinking the worst of us. However, we cannot mind-read so we do not know what others are thinking! \n \n'
             'LABELING: Sometimes we talk to ourselves in a mean way and we use a single negative word to describe ourselves. However, this kind of thinking is unfair and we are too complex to be summed up in a single word! \n \n'
             'FILTERING: This happens when we take note of all the bad things that happen, but ignore any good things. \n \n'
             'OVERESTIMATING: This happens when we believe that something that is unlikely to occur is actually about to happen. \n \n'
             'CATASTROPHIZING: This is when we imagine the worst possible thing is about to happen and we will be unable to cope with it. \n \n'
             'OVERGENERALIZING: This is when we use words like always or never to describe situations or events. This is a problematic way of thinking because it does not take all situation or events into account \n \n')
```

**I am running Python 2.5 on Mac OS X 10.6**

Comment: Here's a clue. Have a look at your code above and take particular notice of the syntax coloring. Who'da thunk SO could be used to debug missing quotes? :-)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your first line in choices variable doesn't have an apostrophe (`'`) at the end.

Answer (score 26):

Not a direct answer to the original question, but since online searching brought me here... I got this error for another reason: a stray parenthesis! But it came from *flake8*. Here's a snippet of code to reproduce it:

```
import socket


def all_good(name):
    name_line = f"Name: {name}")
    print(name_line)
```

I saved this into a file called *error.py*. Now if I run *flake8* on it:

```
$ flake8 error.py 
error.py:1:1: E902 TokenError: EOF in multi-line statement
```

Which is rather puzzling as there is no multi-line statement anywhere! Eventually I found the bug, but the moral of the story is that I'd have found it much quicker if I had run it through the python interpreter:

```
$ python3 error.py 
  File "error.py", line 5
    name_line = f"Name: {name}")
                               ^
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

Fix it:

```
import socket


def all_good(name):
    name_line = f"Name: {name}"
    print(name_line)
```

And now `flake8` will actually do it's job:

```
$ flake8 error.py 
error.py:1:1: F401 'socket' imported but unused
```

It's obvious, but remember: check the code with `python3` first, then run it through linters or other checkers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using the interpreter!

Comment: Thanks this was exactly my issue. Accidentally took off an extra closing parenthesis when reformatting code.

Comment: The clue to `this` being the error, appears to be `flake8` getting lost and reporting the error as occurring at line:1 character:1 i.e. `error.py:1:1: E902 TokenError: EOF in multi-line statement`

Answer (score 11):

You're missing the closing quote on the Fortune-Telling line.

That is easy to find because that is where the syntax highlighting becomes different.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:
Cut out one section of your code and see if that makes that error goes away.
If it does, then the problem is in side that section
If it does not, then find another section to cut out... hint: The section were you working on last :)

Answer (score 0):

After I have added one more closing parenthesis at end the error "Token error: EOF in multi-line statement" has disappeared.

Last line

Before change:
'OVERGENERALIZING: This is when we use words like always or never to describe situations or events. This is a problematic way of thinking because it does not take all situation or events into account \n \n')

After change:
'OVERGENERALIZING: This is when we use words like always or never to describe situations or events. This is a problematic way of thinking because it does not take all situation or events into account \n \n'))

Note: Observe at end one more ) has added. I have tested and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Nagev, searching online for my issue brought me here. I got the same error `EOF in multi-line statement` when trying to run `black` on a Jupyter Notebook cell that just contains an incorrectly formatted f-string:

```py
print(f"{"#"}")
```

It took me a while to find which of the cells caused the error, as the error doesn't say. Running the problematic cell in a Python terminal shows that it still expected additional input to complete the statement, hence why an error was thrown by `black` when the cell unexpectedly ended. The correct cell contents should be:

```py
print(f"{'#'}")
```