# SQL Query Group By inclusion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help modify the following SQL script so that I'm able to do a GROUP BY and replace the character (null).

At the moment I have two tables:

Table 1

```
PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT     COUNTRY_ID     CDC_TYPE
int                   varchar(50)    varchar(50)
666                   DE             U
98                    DE             U
27975373              DE             U
666                   DE             N
```

Table 2

```
PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT     COUNTRY_ID     CDC_TYPE
int                   varchar(50)    varchar(50)
666                   DE             U
75                    DE             U
27975370              DE             U
578                   WE             N
54                    RT             N
```

The results from the sql script produces the following table:

```
is_deleted     PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT     COUNTRY_ID     CDC_TYPE
int            int                   varchar(50)    varchar(50)
1              666                   DE             U
0              666                   DE             U
(null)         769                   DE             U
(null)         578                   WE             N
(null)         54                    RT             N
```

However, I would like to group by the table (in any fashion) and remove or replace the null values, such that the tables appear something as follows:

```
COUNTRY_ID     CDC_TYPE     PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT    is_deleted

DE             U            666                  1
DE             U            666                  0
RT             N            54                   replace null
WE             N            578                  replace null
DE             N            769                  replace null
```

The sql script is as follows:

```
with cmn as 
  ( SELECT a.CDC_TYPE,
           a. PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT, --Add these also in CTE result set 
           a.COUNTRY_ID --Add these also in CTE result set 
    FROM  tabled  a  
    INNER JOIN tablee b  
    ON a.COUNTRY_ID = b.COUNTRY_ID 
    AND a.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = b.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT  
    AND a.CDC_TYPE = 'U'
    )
 SELECT 1 AS is_deleted, 
        a.*  
 FROM  tabled  a  
 INNER JOIN cmn  
 ON a.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE 
 and  a.COUNTRY_ID = cmn.COUNTRY_ID  
 AND a.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = cmn.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT

 UNION ALL  
 SELECT 0 AS is_deleted, 
        b.*  
 FROM tablee  b  
 INNER JOIN cmn  
 ON b.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE 
 and b.COUNTRY_ID = cmn.COUNTRY_ID 
 AND b.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = cmn.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL AS CDC_TYPE,
       a.* 
FROM   tabled a 
WHERE  a.CDC_TYPE = 'N' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL AS CDC_TYPE, 
       b.* 
FROM   tablee b 
WHERE  b.CDC_TYPE = 'N'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please explain the logic for the desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: please see tables as suggestd --Sql Server 2014 Express Edition
--Batches are separated by 'go'

select @@version as 'sql server version'

create table a ( PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT int, COUNTRY_ID varchar(50), CDC_TYPE varchar(50));
insert into a values (666,'DE','U'),(98 ,'DE','U'),(27975373,'DE','U');

select * from a;

create table b ( PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT int, COUNTRY_ID varchar(50), CDC_TYPE varchar(50));
insert into b values (666,'DE','U'),(75 ,'DE','U'),(27975370,'DE','U');

Comment: the desired output is the third image.thanks

Comment: Dont add code in the comment section, just edit your question to include aditional information. The images without explanation doesnt help. :'(

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, thanks and duly noted for next time

Comment: That sql script doesn't produce that "results from the sql script" based on the sample data.  F.e. there's no 769 in both tables, and why no 27975373 in the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps use a string for the "is_deleted" in all of those unioned queries.

But then maybe this query could also be simplified via a FULL JOIN

For example:

```
SELECT PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT, COUNTRY_ID, CDC_TYPE, IS_DELETED
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    COALESCE(d.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT, e.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT) AS PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT, 
    COALESCE(d.COUNTRY_ID, e.COUNTRY_ID) AS COUNTRY_ID, 
    COALESCE(d.CDC_TYPE, e.CDC_TYPE) AS CDC_TYPE,
    (CASE 
     WHEN d.CDC_TYPE = e.CDC_TYPE AND d.CDC_TYPE = 'U' THEN '1' 
     WHEN d.CDC_TYPE = e.CDC_TYPE AND d.CDC_TYPE = 'N' THEN '0' 
     ELSE '' 
     END) AS IS_DELETED
    FROM tabled d
    FULL JOIN tablee e 
      ON e.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = d.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT 
     AND e.COUNTRY_ID = d.COUNTRY_ID 
     AND e.CDC_TYPE = d.CDC_TYPE
    WHERE d.CDC_TYPE = e.CDC_TYPE 
       OR d.CDC_TYPE = 'N'
       OR e.CDC_TYPE = 'N'
) AS cmn 
GROUP BY PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT, COUNTRY_ID, CDC_TYPE, IS_DELETED
ORDER BY IS_DELETED DESC, PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT, COUNTRY_ID, CDC_TYPE;
```

Comment: absolutely perfect. Really very much appreciated. Sorry for badly worded question.. However, you nailed it.

Comment: Just one last comment, I tried entering the commands on my spark.sql by enclosing your commands within """YOURCOMMANDSHERE""", but it returns an error saying  ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 73)). If you're not familiar with spark.sql don't worry, if you familiare with spark.sql your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Carltonp Nope, never used that. But a bit of googling hinted that stuff like that could happen if there's missing apostrophes somewhere. F.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885136/)

Comment: can someone help modify the original script in the question so that the Is_deleted column is removed?

Comment: @Carltonp Not sure what you mean. You created the question, so you can edit it. And this question was about what's supposed to show in the "is_deleted"? Do you mean that it should have another alias name? If then I don't really see the point, once you got something that works you can edit it for your personal scripts anyway, the question doesn't need to be adapted for that.

Comment: thanks for getting in touch. I created the question but I didn't create the script. It was kindly compiled for me, but I can't get in touch with person that original wrote the script

Comment: I tried editing by removing `SELECT 1 AS is_deleted, 
        a.*  
 FROM  tabled  a  
 INNER JOIN cmn  
 ON a.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE 
 and  a.COUNTRY_ID = cmn.COUNTRY_ID  
 AND a.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = cmn.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT

 UNION ALL  
 SELECT 0 AS is_deleted, 
        b.*  
 FROM tablee  b  
 INNER JOIN cmn  
 ON b.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE 
 and b.COUNTRY_ID = cmn.COUNTRY_ID 
 AND b.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = cmn.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT
UNION ALL ` but it kept on throwing errors

Comment: @Carltonp When you use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` then the column names or alias names from the top query will be shown for the result.  So I assume it's because by removing those 2 that the first column is now named "CDC_TYPE". So change that alias name to "is_deleted"? And btw, using `*` has a disadvantage that if 1 of the tables get a new column, that the number of column in each query isn't the same anymore.  So explicit listing the column names is normally safer.